# Compile emacs with xwidget under OSX?

Tags: osx

**How do I compile Emacs with `xwidget` under OSX?**

When I tried to run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/emacs-xwidgets --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 --with-xwidgets` I get an error `configure: error: xwidgets requested but gtk3 not used.`. But it looks like I have an gtk+3.0 -

`` sandric@sandric-mac ~/emacs> brew install gtk+3
Error: gtk+3-3.18.9 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink gtk+3` ``

It looks like I don't have `gtk3` package in `pkg-config` - 

`sandric@sandric-mac ~> pkg-config --list-all
libzmq                              libzmq - 0MQ c++ library
gio-unix-2.0                        GIO unix specific APIs - unix specific headers for glib I/O library
libusb-1.0                          libusb-1.0 - C API for USB device access from Linux, Mac OS X, Windows and OpenBSD/NetBSD userspace
gobject-introspection-no-export-1.0 gobject-introspection - GObject Introspection
libecpg_compat                      libecpg_compat - PostgreSQL libecpg_compat library
gio-2.0                             GIO - glib I/O library
libcdt                              libcdt - Container DataType library
cairo-gobject                       cairo-gobject - gobject functions for cairo graphics library
harfbuzz-icu                        harfbuzz - HarfBuzz text shaping library ICU integration
cairo-quartz-font                   cairo-quartz-font - Quartz font backend for cairo graphics library
libpng16                            libpng - Loads and saves PNG files
dbus-1                              dbus - Free desktop message bus
ImageMagick++                       ImageMagick++ - Magick++ - C++ API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
cairo-ps                            cairo-ps - PostScript surface backend for cairo graphics library
gmodule-2.0                         GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
lcms                                lcms - LCMS Color Management Library
glib-2.0                            GLib - C Utility Library
ImageMagick                         ImageMagick - ImageMagick - convert, edit, and compose images (ABI Q16)
Magick++-6.Q16                      Magick++ - Magick++ - C++ API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
gimpthumb-2.0                       GIMP Thumb - GIMP Thumbnail Library
gdlib                               gd - GD graphics library
libpcre2-16                         libpcre2-16 - PCRE2 - Perl compatible regular expressions C library (2nd API) with 16 bit character support
pango                               Pango - Internationalized text handling
uuid                                OSSP uuid - Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) Library
babl                                babl - Dynamic, any to any, pixel format conversion library
MagickWand                          MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
libedit                             libedit - command line editor library provides generic line editing, history, and tokenization functions.
libublio                            ublio - UBLIO caching library
libicns                             libicns - Loads and saves Macintosh icns files
libcgraph                           libcgraph - Graph library (file i/o, dot language parsing, graph, subgraph, node, edge, attribute, data structure manipulation)
libpcrecpp                          libpcrecpp - PCRECPP - C++ wrapper for PCRE
pangoft2                            Pango FT2 and Pango Fc - Freetype 2.0 and fontconfig font support for Pango
libevent_pthreads                   libevent_pthreads - libevent_pthreads adds pthreads-based threading support to libevent
gdk-pixbuf-2.0                      GdkPixbuf - Image loading and scaling
gmodule-no-export-2.0               GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
MagickCore-6.Q16                    MagickCore - MagickCore - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
osxfuse                             fuse - OSXFUSE
libcroco-0.6                        libcroco - a CSS2 Parsing and manipulation Library in C.
libxdot                             libxdot - Library for parsing graphs in xdot format
liblzma                             liblzma - General purpose data compression library
gtk+-3.0                            GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
libssh2                             libssh2 - Library for SSH-based communication
gobject-introspection-1.0           gobject-introspection - GObject Introspection
Magick++                            Magick++ - Magick++ - C++ API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
gtk+-unix-print-2.0                 GTK+ - GTK+ Unix print support
libiodbc                            iODBC - iODBC Driver Manager
libfontforgeexe                     libfontforgeexe - for embedding the FontForge UI in a program.
gdk-2.0                             GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit (quartz target)
gtk-mac-integration-gtk2            gtk-mac-integration-gtk2 - Mac menu bar and dock integration for GTK+
gtk-mac-integration-gtk3            gtk-mac-integration-gtk3 - Mac menu bar and dock integration for GTK+
yaml-0.1                            LibYAML - Library to parse and emit YAML
libssl                              OpenSSL - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries
libpcre2-32                         libpcre2-32 - PCRE2 - Perl compatible regular expressions C library (2nd API) with 32 bit character support
apr-util-1                          APR Utils - Companion library for APR
libevent                            libevent - libevent is an asynchronous notification event loop library
openssl                             OpenSSL - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
libevent_openssl                    libevent_openssl - libevent_openssl adds openssl-based TLS support to libevent
mysqlclient                         mysqlclient - MySQL client library
cairo-pdf                           cairo-pdf - PDF surface backend for cairo graphics library
gimpui-2.0                          GIMP UI - GIMP User Interface Library
apr-1                               APR - The Apache Portable Runtime library
gdk-quartz-2.0                      GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit (quartz target)
pangocairo                          Pango Cairo - Cairo rendering support for Pango
gmodule-export-2.0                  GModule - Dynamic module loader for GLib
libgvpr                             libgvpr - The GVPR library
gimp-2.0                            GIMP - GIMP Library
libpq                               libpq - PostgreSQL libpq library
ImageMagick++-6.Q16                 ImageMagick++ - Magick++ - C++ API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
Wand-6.Q16                          MagickWand - MagickCore - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
gsettings-desktop-schemas           gsettings-desktop-schemas - Shared GSettings schemas for the desktop, including helper headers
pixman-1                            Pixman - The pixman library (version 1)
libpcre2-8                          libpcre2-8 - PCRE2 - Perl compatible regular expressions C library (2nd API) with 8 bit character support
cairo-quartz-image                  cairo-quartz-image - Quartz Image surface backend for cairo graphics library
gtk+-quartz-2.0                     GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library (quartz target)
libpathplan                         libpathplan - Library for planning polyline and bezier paths around polygon obstacles
libpcre16                           libpcre16 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 16 bit character support
libfontforge                        libfontforge - a font manipulation library.
libtiff-4                           libtiff - Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library.
gobject-2.0                         GObject - GLib Type, Object, Parameter and Signal Library
libgvc                              libgvc - The GraphVizContext library
gtk+-unix-print-3.0                 GTK+ - GTK+ Unix print support
libpng                              libpng - Loads and saves PNG files
gthread-2.0                         GThread - Thread support for GLib
cairo-fc                            cairo-fc - Fontconfig font backend for cairo graphics library
fontconfig                          Fontconfig - Font configuration and customization library
libecpg                             libecpg - PostgreSQL libecpg library
cairo                               cairo - Multi-platform 2D graphics library
gdk-3.0                             GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit
pygobject-2.0                       PyGObject - Python bindings for GObject
libcrypto                           OpenSSL-libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptography library
libpcreposix                        libpcreposix - PCREPosix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre
cairo-png                           cairo-png - PNG functions for cairo graphics library
cairo-ft                            cairo-ft - FreeType font backend for cairo graphics library
epoxy                               epoxy - epoxy GL dispatch Library
gtk-mac-integration                 gtk-mac-integration-gtk2 - Mac menu bar and dock integration for GTK+
Wand                                MagickWand - MagickCore - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
atk                                 Atk - Accessibility Toolkit
libpcre2-posix                      libpcre2-posix - Posix compatible interface to libpcre2-8
fish                                fish - fish, the friendly interactive shell
libntfs-3g                          libntfs-3g - NTFS-3G Read/Write Driver Library
libczmq                             libczmq - The high-level C binding for 0MQ
cairo-svg                           cairo-svg - SVG surface backend for cairo graphics library
libsodium                           libsodium - A portable, cross-compilable, installable, packageable fork of NaCl, with a compatible API.
gdk-quartz-3.0                      GDK - GTK+ Drawing Kit
cairo-quartz                        cairo-quartz - Quartz surface backend for cairo graphics library
fuse                                fuse - OSXFUSE
harfbuzz                            harfbuzz - HarfBuzz text shaping library
libtls                              LibreSSL-libtls - Secure communications using the TLS socket protocol.
MagickWand-6.Q16                    MagickWand - MagickWand - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
libpgtypes                          libpgtypes - PostgreSQL libpgtypes library
pycairo                             Pycairo - Python bindings for cairo
libpcre                             libpcre - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 8 bit character support
cairo-script                        cairo-script - script surface backend for cairo graphics library
ImageMagick-6.Q16                   ImageMagick - ImageMagick - convert, edit, and compose images (ABI Q16)
libpcre32                           libpcre32 - PCRE - Perl compatible regular expressions C library with 32 bit character support
gail-3.0                            Gail - GNOME Accessibility Implementation Library
cairo-tee                           cairo-tee - tee surface backend for cairo graphics library
freetype2                           FreeType 2 - A free, high-quality, and portable font engine.
slang                               slang - S-Lang programming library and interpreter
MagickCore                          MagickCore - MagickCore - C API for ImageMagick (ABI Q16)
gtk+-quartz-3.0                     GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
librsvg-2.0                         librsvg - library that renders svg files
gtk+-2.0                            GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library (quartz target)
oniguruma                           oniguruma - Regular expression library
harfbuzz-gobject                    harfbuzz - HarfBuzz text shaping library GObject integration
pygtk-2.0                           PyGTK - Python bindings for GTK+ and related libraries
gail                                Gail - GNOME Accessibility Implementation Library`

Comment: Are you going to be using `x11`, or do you intend this to be a part of the standard GUI version on OSX without `x11`?  See also my related question on reddit -- **What is the macports equivalent for xwidgets?**:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4bfef1/what_is_the_macports_equivalent_for_xwidgets/?st=irehfr3t&sh=2201fea7

Comment: Get the same error message here, after appending `--without-ns`, it now says `configure: error: xwidgets requested but WebKitGTK+ not found.` Though I have installed `webkitgtk` via homebrew.

Comment: Emacs does not support x11, see this conversation https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-08/msg00415.html

Answer (score 2):

I have gtk+-3 installed by homebrew and I can see it using `pkg-config --list-all`. I have the following in my .zshrc, which may matter:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

To enable the gtk3 toolkit you also need to disable nextstep as building option, adding `--without-ns` to you configure.

Comment: and you managed to compile emacs with xwidgets? And run webkit in it?

Comment: I have not tried yet. If you do an export with that line, is gtk+3 detected by pkg-config?

Comment: I can now go further in the configure with the --without-ns option, but I don’t have the correct version of webkitgtk+ installed to successfully build it.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the --without-ns option, you also need the --without-x11 option, to force gtk+3 to use quartz.

`brew install --build-from-source at-spi2-core at-spi2-atk cairo harfbuzz pango gtk+ librsvg gnome-icon-theme gtk+3 --without-ns --without-x --without-x11 --with-gtk+3`

Comment: I needed to install `giflib` with `brew install giflib` as well for `libgif/libungif`

Comment: Did you manage to install gnu emacs with xwidgets support on macos?

Answer (score 0):

i also needed X11 emacs on OSX, and chased stackexchange leads like this one all day with no success (10.14).

what finally worked was an approach with macports instead of homebrew:

```
sudo port install emacs +x11
```

solution courtesy of @mariusm
[stackoverflow 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735651/how-to-run-emacs-in-ssh-x-from-linux-to-mac-os-x-with-xforwarding)

Comment: Funny note, my laptop totally crashed and I had not backed up my notes on how to do the initial configuration and build. All I remembered was that it was very difficult to get the right Emacs that I wanted. But this note says it all, I thought I might be helping others but I helped myself !!