# Embed a youtube video in org-mode buffer

Tags: org-mode, previewing, video

I would like to display a youtube (or locally hosted) video inside an org-mode buffer, similar to how `org-toggle-inline-images` will preview an image file.  How can I do this?

Comment: Something like that should become possible with xwidget in emacs25. See https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4srze9/watching_youtube_inside_emacs_25/

Comment: I am unaware of anyone who has successfully done this on Emacs for OSX:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/25037/compile-emacs-with-xwidget-under-osx  So, it looks like the xwidget option for Emacs only works on Linux at this time.

Comment: Just for your info: The video about xwidget: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2YdjpWJJHs

Comment: I wonder if emacs can play huge (very long) animated gifs ... :) (`ffmpeg` can convert video to animated gif ... no sound though).